# CSS: How do i scale a container to the width of a dynamically sized child?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page with several adaptive containers which will contain several static-sized elements as well as an optional element with dynamic width and height.

The scaling in the CSS is a little rough-cut as I gutted it out of a larger sheet, but I hope it shows what I'm going for.

So, what I can't get to work is this: I would very much like the dynamic container to take the width of the dynamic elements within it.

The container should be the width of the dynamic element, and the static sized elements inside should order themselves within the width of the container, expanding the height as needed.

I should also point out that I would appreciate a pure CSS solution. I don't have that option where this is to be deployed.

---

EDIT: I seem to have caused a bit of confusion, so I will clarify.
The static container is precisely as I want it. It wraps correctly and everything is fine. The container containing the dynamic (Blue) element is the one that I have trouble with. I want the container with the blue item to take the width of the blue item. The red items should wrap and extend the HEIGHT of the dynamic container if needed.

I cannot change the HTML layout. I can add extra classes to the HTML if needed.

I made an updated fiddle with how I would like the result to look. But I need it to be dynamic. So I can't just set the width of the container, which is how I made this: https://jsfiddle.net/mnybon/nwa0gx1h/1/

---

I have a js-fiddle here as well as the initial revision code for archiving
https://jsfiddle.net/mnybon/nwa0gx1h/

```css
.site {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container {
  min-width: 30vw;
  max-width: 100%;  
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container.fixed{
  width: 30vw;
}

.fixedsize-element {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}

.variable-element {
  width: 44vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="container dynamic">
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="variable-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container fixed">
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>

    <div class="fixedsize-element">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a wrapper around fixed size element or not ?

Comment: Not:) I cannot change the structure of the HTML, but i can add additional classes. I am going to update the question, as i see i have caused a bit of confusion overall here.

Comment: Can you try this 

.container.dynamic{
  display: table-caption;
}

Comment: Do you want 2 containers side by side?

Comment: I want the containers to wrap as well to fill the entire screen. They do not have to have the same height, or be perfectly justified, but they do need to allow any number of containers.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're looking for [flexible boxes css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Example:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dynamicsize-element {
    flex: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpje8Lyb/1/

Comment: I think i might have been unclear in my question. I have attempted to update it to make a bit more sense. I want the container with the blue element to be the width of the blue element. The red elements should wrap and extend the height of the container if needed. The container with no blue element should remain unchanged.

Comment: @Martin Nielsen can you explane  with image how u want

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mnybon/nwa0gx1h/1/ I updated the fiddle to emulate what i want: The container keeping the size of the blue element. But i need a dynamic solution, as the blue container can change its width.

Comment: This seems to be very close to what i want. It does seem however, that the size of the blue box is not really respected. I removed the static size and tried adding some short paragraphs inside, and the blue box stays a lot wider than the content inside it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: ok it's time to do a small trick, that you will put a `div` inside `dynamicsize-element`. I have updated my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rpje8Lyb/4/

Comment: maybe it still not match the requirement

Answer (score 2):

If you want 2 containers Vertically aligned and it should occupy the variable sized child element width try this

> display:table-caption ->These elements behave like  HTML elements. 
>   but it causes vertical layout.

Add this CSS

```
.container.dynamic{ display: table-caption; }
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/nwa0gx1h/3/)**